# RSpec PostgreSQL results not consistent running all/single test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I've got an issue with testing my application with an PostgreSQL database. In our current setup we use PostgreSQL for our production environment and SQLite3 for our development and testing environment. Because this can lead to unexpected behavior the development and testing enviroments need to switch to PostgreSQL.

Switching the testing environment is the toughest part. Some tests run correctly, when running one single spec file, but fail when running all tests together using Guard. When running test manually in my development it behaves expected.

Here's an exapmle. The test that is failing is the last one where I'm switching to the second user and test if can the @items contain anything. It resturn an empty an empty array.

```
# /spec/controllers/materials_controller_spec.rb

describe MaterialsController do
  def create_users
    @user_1 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    @user_2 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    @admin = FactoryBot.create(:super_admin)

    @private_group = Group.find_or_create_by(name: "Private")
    @shared_group = Group.find_or_create_by(name: "Shared")
    @project_group = Group.find_or_create_by(name: "Project")

    @project = FactoryBot.create(:project)
    @user_1.projects << @project
    @user_2.projects << @project

    sign_in @user_1
  end

  def create_my_private_material
    @my_private_material = FactoryBot.create(:material, user: @user_1, group: @private_group, name: "Test01")
  end

  def create_my_private_material_2
    @my_private_material_2 = FactoryBot.create(:material, user: @user_1, group: @private_group)
  end

  def create_your_private_material
    @your_private_material = FactoryBot.create(:material, user: @user_2, group: @private_group)
  end

  def create_my_project_material
    @my_project_material = FactoryBot.create(:material, user: @user_1, group: @project_group, project: @project)
  end

  def create_your_shared_material
    @your_shared_material = FactoryBot.create(:material, user: @user_2, group: @shared_group)
  end

  def create_all_materials
    create_my_private_material
    create_my_private_material_2
    create_your_private_material
    create_my_project_material
    create_your_shared_material
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      create_users
      create_all_materials
    end
    context "as material owner" do
      it "renders the index template" do
        get :index

        expect(assigns(:items)).to contain_exactly(@my_project_material, @my_private_material_2, @my_private_material)
        expect(response).to render_template("index")
      end
    end

    context "as being the owner and a current project set using the project scope" do
      before do
        @user_1.current_project_id = @project.id
        @user_1.save
      end
      it "should assing only the the materials the belong to the current project" do
        get :index, params: { scope: 'project' }
        expect(assigns(:items)).to contain_exactly(@my_project_material)
      end
    end

    context "as not being the material owner and no default project" do
      before do
        sign_out @user_1
        sign_in @user_2
      end
      it "filters out the materials based on group and project" do
        get :index
        expect(assigns(:items)).to contain_exactly(@your_private_material, @your_shared_material)
      end
    end

    context "as not being the owner, with a current project and using the project scope" do
      before do
        @user_2.current_project_id = @project.id
        @user_2.save
        sign_out @user_1
        sign_in @user_2
      end
      it "should assign only the materials the belong to the project" do
        get :index, params: { scope: 'project', project_id: @project.id }

        expect(assigns(:items)).to contain_exactly(@my_project_material)
      end
    end
  end
```

I've done some debugging and found a couple of things:

1. The error in the tests are consistent when running all the tests.
2. When adding `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation` in the before block seems to fix some tests.
3. Changing the number connections allowed to the test database to `1` does work for the controller tests but is a problem in my feature tests because it somehow seems to require at least to connections.

So the problem seems to be related to the advantages to a PostgreSQL database being able to handle multiple requests. But what I don't understand that running one single test would pass but running all tests would fail some test. I've searched around on the internet to find similar related issue's but could find any good post or question.

If needed I can post different test that are failing as well but I think it's all related to the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use rspecs [`let` and  `let!` helper methods](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) instead of this mess. You can also use `FactoryBot.create_list` to create an array of records instead of being so wordy.

Comment: Its also unclear if you have setup DatabaseCleaner to properly clean the slate in `rails_helper.rb`. The fact that using `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation` between specs solves some of the ordering issues indicates that the root cause may be with the test setup and how your factories are defined (do they produce unique records repeatedly?) and not actually the database at all.

Comment: If you google for "flapping tests" you´ll find quite a lot of resources.

Comment: Thank @max for your reply. Enough to (re)think about. The tests are getting quite messy in this way. The tests needs to run a lot of different situations with small differences. I'll dive deeper into my setup.